# Routing from redux-saga or any custom middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I am using React and Redux, React-Router for an application, to handle side effects, I'm using the redux-saga library. I would love to know how route from my sagas. For example.

consider, the event flow

1. USER REGISTERS and application dispatches a SIGN_UP action
2. A saga 'takes' the SIGN_UP action and performs some sign up task.
3. on task completion, i want the user taken (routed) to the Login Page.

And I will prefer this to be handled in the redux-saga, i will of course appreciate a better or alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, Thank you. For anyone who might want to do the same thing, simply pass the history object gotten from the react router useHistory hook to the payload of the action being dispatched and use the push method to handle routing to another page

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer yet (and when i will - I'll edit this) - I just think your choice of solution (and I'm aware this is also the 'react-router' solution) is not great.

Basically you're making the 'Registration' component "aware" of the router which I find annoying...
'navigation' is a side-effect and as such it should be handled from SAGA.
you can try to use 'connected react router', i tried and failed... but I have a largely complex application...